# Http request fail on simulator

Tags: php, http, react-native, httprequest

I'm trying to do a https request to call a server-hosted PHP file in my react native app, so I tried this way:

```
fetch('https://XXX.XXX.XX.XXX/m_getApplications.php?offset=0&dateOrder=date_created')
      .then((response) => response)
      .then((responseJson) => {
        console.warn(responseJson);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
     });
```

but the only thing I can get is a 404 error page from CPanel.

But the crazy thing is that when I call the SAME link on Postman (http request tool), I'm getting my JSON and everything is working well. I thought that it could be the emulator, but I tried on iOS & Android and both of them are getting the error.

I already set the NSAllowsArbitraryLoads on true but there's no way.

Has anyone encountered the problem already?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! I tried with the domain name instead of the ip address of the server, and it's working now.